# How to get friendlists of the not current session user?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I already read facebook api

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

I trying to request friendlists using a not current session as follows:

---

1. get access token via my app

> https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?
>       client_id=YOUR_APP_ID&client_secret=YOUR_APP_SECRET&grant_type=client_credentials

I surely obtained the access token. as shown below:

`access_token=1234567890|-abcdefghijkl`

2. request friendlists using a access token.

`https://graph.facebook.com/1023456789/friendlists?access_token=1234567890|-abcdefghijkl`

but, the following error message has been received.

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "A user access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 102
   }
}
```

ID is not the current user session. As you know, if using a the current user session. i can get friends lists in without any problem.

`https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=1234567890|-abcdefghijkl`

My question can be summarized as follows:

**How to get friends list using a user ID that not the current session? I think must obtain friendlists permission when i get accesstoken. if the right. How do I do that?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the access token you got is the one where, a user was redirected to the FB login page and redirected back to your application then read along.

The documentation can be a bit confusing. [This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/public-profile-and-friend-list/) states that:

> When a user logs into your app and you request no additional
>   permissions, the app will have access to only the user's public
>   profile and friend list.

Without digging into the documentation specifically into the permission list, one might think that when `read_friendlists` is added to the `scope` the user's friend list will be available, but it won't be. [This page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/login/extended-permissions/) clearly indicated that reading a Facebook user's friend list requires an `extended permission`.

So you need to add `read_friendlists` as one of your scope. Here's a sample request:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?type=user_agent
    &client_id=YOUR_FB_APPID
    &redirect_uri=YOUR_DOMAIN
    &scope=read_friendlists
```

Comment: How to add `read_friendlists` URI? I trying google it. but failed.

Comment: See my updated answer. Btw, are you using any SDK (e.g. the jsd sdk)?

Answer (score 0):

You need to ask for the `read_friendlists` permission from a user when they authenticate your app. And, to read the friendlists, you need a user access token, not an app access token. Obviously, the relevant user's access token.

At this point, you have 1-2 hours until their access_token expires. During this period, you can access the user's friendlists. After the token expired, you will need to wait until they log in again. Alternatively, you can look into [Extending Access Tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/howtos/login/extending-tokens/).